# Bug with PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, parsing

I'm doing a parser for a site with PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser, but when i reach this code:

```
<table class="datatable"><thead></thead><thead><tr>
<th scope="col">p</th>
<th scope="col">b</th>
<th scope="col">c</th>
<th scope="col">time</th>
<th scope="col">pf</th>
</tr></thead>
<tbody><tr><td>1</td><td>Test</td><td><a href="?test=887&amp;action=2">Test</a></td><td>02'09''85</td><td><center>33</center></td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>Test</td><td><a href="?test=887&amp;action=2">Test</a></td><td>02'09''85</td><td><center>33</center></td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>Test</td><td><a href="?test=887&amp;action=2">Test</a></td><td>02'09''85</td><td><center>33</center></td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>Test</td><td><a href="?test=887&amp;action=2">Test</a></td><td>02'09''85</td><td><center>33</center></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Will merge a problem, when i found a tables with the SAME code like this, my parser work perfectly:

```
<table class="datatable"><thead></thead><thead><tr>
<th scope="col">p</th>
<th scope="col">b</th>
<th scope="col">c</th>
<th scope="col">d</th>
<th scope="col">time</th>
<th scope="col">pf</th>
</tr></thead>
<tbody><tr><td>1</td><td><a href="?test=11637&amp;action=2">test</a></td><td>1111</td><td>Test</td><td>04'44''19</td><td><center>10</center></td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td><a href="?test=11637&amp;action=2">test</a></td><td>1111</td><td>Test</td><td>04'44''19</td><td><center>10</center></td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td><a href="?test=11637&amp;action=2">test</a></td><td>1111</td><td>Test</td><td>04'44''19</td><td><center>10</center></td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td><a href="?test=11637&amp;action=2">test</a></td><td>1111</td><td>Test</td><td>04'44''19</td><td><center>10</center></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

My parser code is this:

```
<?php

include('../simple_html_dom.php');

function get_results(...bla bla ...,$tr){
    $html2 = file_get_html("...URL.com");

    $e = $html2->find('table.datatable', 13);
    $str2 = str_get_html($e);

    foreach($str2->find('table') as $g){
        foreach($g->find('tr') as $key=>$a){
            if($key == 0)
                continue;

            if($tr <= 53){
                 $result['p'] = $a->find('td', 0)->innertext;
                 $result['time'] = strip_tags($a->find('td', 4)->innertext);
                  $result['pf'] = $a->find('td', 5)->find('center', 0)->innertext;
           }else{
            $result['p'] = $a->find('td', 0)->innertext;
            $result['time'] = $a->find('td', 3)->innertext;
            $result['pf'] = $a->find('td', 4)->innertext;
        }
        $results[] = $result;
        }
    }

    echo 'c';
    $html2->clear();
    unset($html2);

}

error_reporting(-1);
get_results(...bla bla ...,$tr);
echo 'finish';

?>
```

When the parser get first CODE/TABLE with 5 coloumn it dosn't work because it tell me this:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\blabla\test1.php on line 22
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\blabla\test1.php on line 23

When i get the second CODE/TABLE with the table with 6 coloumn it work perfectly, the parser take all records, the first code take me firsts records but after few record he give me that error.
I tried to use foreach just for 'td' or 'tbody tr' 'tr' but nothing, it's buggy with those tags, tried to assign to a variable the code html but the result it's the same, tried var_dump too, i really don't know how to fix this problem.

Comment: basic debugging: `var_dump($a)` at the point you get those non-object warnings and see what's really in there. most likely the ->find() call is failing to find anything.

Comment: already used, wasn't helpfull..

Comment: so `var_dump($a->find('tr'))` (without the index) and see what does get found at that point.

Comment: with your code "var_dump($a->find('tr'))" found so many array and so many code without sense, with this var_dump($a->find('tr')->innertext) i found this: NULL NULL NULL .

Comment: can you explain the function call get_results( ...) and arguments so we can replicate? also what do you need to parse from the table?

Comment: Okay, the function get_results get records from a determinate table, the arguments of this functions aren't important, because the params I pass need for the url, so the only params important is $tr, that mean the tipology of the table, i write both of tipology, the first code is < 53 else analyze the other tables, the code html are right, so i take just 3 coloumn, p, time, pf.